# Using window.setTimeout() and window.setInterval() in this situation

Tags: javascript, settimeout, clearinterval

This might be a newb question but....
Recently, I have been using window.setTimeout which makes a recursive call to the parent function, which makes an ajax poll to the server.

```
function connectToVM(portal) {
    //making the ajax call here....
   if(response.responseText !== "")
     {
    windowInterval = window.setTimeout(function() {
        connectToVM(portal)
    }
    , 4000);
   }
  }
```

`windowInterval` is my global var here.

```
if(!checkIfChartExists()) {
  window.clearInterval(windowInterval);
}
```

Now, instead of making use of variables here, I know that I can simple pass the `function` to `clearTimeout`, but that also causes all the other intervals to be stopped :(

The reason why I am doing this is the server does a timeout, only when there is a response.
My scenario is, I have a chart which updates every timeout interval. 
AFAIK, when we set the interval, there is a specific value set to the variable(if set to a variable). So when I print my variable(every time when the timeout function is called), I get some int values which are unique.

I have many tabs, and many tabs can have same chart.. which just makes use of the same interval which is triggered earlier.
Now I have just 1 chart.. But I have many charts to show which are of the same type. Say gauge Chart.

I also have to clear the timeout whenever there is no chart present in the current selected tab - which I am doing.
So I am planning to make just 1 function which just makes the call to the server by passing in the required params to this function.

But in order to poll, I am using window.setTimeout thing I mentioned above.
This works for 1 chart.
Now, I try to add 1 more chart, with different set of params to poll the server, I will need to make use of some different setTimeout function, which has a id different than that of the earlier triggered timeout.

I also have to consider that if the 1st chart is already present, the timeout is already triggered and have to keep it running.
So, now I have to trigger the second timeout.
But there is no `second timeout` here.

I was wondering if there is any alternate approach to this, as I can't really predict how many chart's there will be on runtime.

`Question 1 : Can we flood our browser with many timeout's?`

`Question 2 : How to get the id of that particular timeout, so that I can clearTimeout(id) on it?`

`Question 3 : Since we can't assign / make variables on the fly, how to set / make such a data structure which can hold such a pointer to the particular chart's index / id.. so that we can easily get hold of it and clear it.`

`Question 4 : Is this the only way we can poll the server(via AJAX) if we have to poll continually?`

Lastly, I recognize this is a very `complex` issue I have posted in here. But I am sure I will find some useful information about the approach from the forums.
I don't have much experience doing all these stuffs in JS, but any help is appreciated!

---

**Update**

Sorry I have to post my code in here.. But I am using Extjs to get my chart portlets. My code for the function `connectToVM` is this :

```
function connectToVM(portalId, host, port, user, passwd, db) {
      try{
        if(Ext.getCmp(portalId)) 
        {
            var gaugeChartForTitle = Ext.getCmp(portalId);

            if(typeof portalOriginalTitle === 'undefined')
                portalOriginalTitle = gaugeChartForTitle.title;

            var gaugeChartDiv = document.getElementById(portalId);

            Ext.Ajax.request({
                      url: "/connectToVM?" +
                            Ext.urlEncode({
                                host: host,
                                port: port,
                                user: user,
                                passwd: passwd,
                                db: db
                            }),
                      method: 'GET',
                      success: function (response, options) {

                          if(response.responseText !== "")
                          {
                              gaugeChartDiv.style.background = "";

                              gaugeChartForTitle.setTitle(portalOriginalTitle);

                              console.log("Virtual Machine at "+ host +" :  BUSY % : "+response.responseText);

                              virtualMachineStore.loadData(generateVirtualMachineData(response.responseText)); //Setting the data1 value of the store and loading it for display!

                              windowInterval = window.setTimeout(function() {
                                  connectToVM(portalId, host, port, user, passwd, db)
                                }
                              , 4000);
                          } 
                          else 
                          {
                              windowInterval = window.setTimeout(function() {
                                  connectToVM(portalId, host, port, user, passwd, db)
                                }
                              , 10000); //Retry every 10 seconds to check if the connection is established!

                              gaugeChartDiv.style.background = "red";
                              gaugeChartForTitle.setTitle(portalOriginalTitle +" - Connection Failure. Reconnecting!");
                          }
                      },
                      failure: function ( result, request) { 
                     }
              });
         }
             }
             catch(err) {
             }
         }
```

Now, I trigger my function using this :

```
function setWindowIntervalForVM(portalId) {
       //console.log("isIntervalActivated inside setWindowIntervalForVM() : "+isIntervalActivated);
       if(!isIntervalActivated) {
           connectToVM(portalId, host, port, user, pwd, db);
       }
    }

   function checkIfWindowIntervalIsActivated(portal) {
       if(!isIntervalActivated) {
            setWindowIntervalForVM(portal.id);
            isIntervalActivated = true;
        } else {
            window.clearInterval(windowInterval);
            windowInterval = null;
            isIntervalActivated = false;
        }
   }
```

So `checkIfWindowIntervalIsActivated()` is my parent function call which I call in these scenarios :

**1)** Whenever the `Gauge Chart` is newly created.. I Trigger this call and have a `boolean isIntervalActivated` which if it is `false`, triggers the server poll.

**2)** So now if I have the chart already in tab 1(since the user selected it), I now change to `tab 2` which does not have it. So I simply set `isIntervalActivated` to true which stops the poll. `This is handled for 1 chart`. Now the question here is, if I want to make this function `re-usable`, say I want to drop one more chart of same `type` but with different `server parameters` to poll, how to make use of the same `windowInterval` variable which has my 1st chart's triggered timeout value. P.S: The value changes for every ajax request it makes. So there'z no `1 single` value :(

**3)** I stop the poll whenever there is no `chart` of same type present.. in other tab. which makes perfect sense. Now, I am caching all my portlets whenever user drops in a new portlet / on the page load, pulling all the user configured portlets. In such a `case`, I have to trigger all of the `charts'` ajax calls.. each polling to its `configured destination`. Now, I do not know how many charts there will be, as in my function name, I am polling to VM's. So if the user consumes VM1, it switches to VM2 and so on.

So it's absolutely impossible to just create same function for many such similar charts.
So just wanted to check if I can `re-use` the same timeOut thing, or take a totally `different` approach to this problem :( :(

I hope it's a bit clear now, if not I can explain my situation more.
Please ask me more questions if required :)
Thanks again!

Comment: This question will likely get closed - you need to be concise and ask a single question, preferably supported with code samples, links to relevant info you've already researched, etc.  Please read the FAQ on how to ask questions here.

Comment: Ah sorry for that.. editing my question with `code samples`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly and you're trying to support multiple charts updating concurrently, I'd switch from keeping the chart data inside the `connectToVM()` closure to an explicit array of chart objects and use a single interval to update all charts.

Something like the following (treat it as pseudo-code):

```
var charts = [
  // an array of chart objects, see addChart()
];

function addChart() {
  // when you need to add or remove a chart, update the charts object, like this:
  charts.push({
    update: updateChart,
    nextUpdateTime: null, // or Date.now() if you don't care about old browsers.
    chartData: {host: ..., port: ..., user: ..., passwd: ..., db: ...,
                originalTitle: ..., portalId: ...},
  });
  restartUpdates();
}

var activeInterval = null;
function restartUpdates() {
  if (activeInterval) {
    clearInterval(activeInterval);
  }
  activeInterval = setInterval(updateCharts, 5000);
}

// updates all active charts
function updateCharts() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
    var chart = charts[i];
    if (chart.nextUpdateTime !== null && chart.nextUpdateTime < now) {
      chart.nextUpdateTime = null; // chart.update() will re-set this
      try {
        chart.update(chart);
      } catch(e) {
        // handle the error
      }
    }
  }

// update a single chart.
// @param |chart| is an item from the |charts| array.
function updateChart(chart) {
  // ...same as your connectToVM() using properties from chart.chartData...
  Ext.Ajax.request(
    // ...
      success: function (response, options) {
        // ...same as before...
        // ...but instead of re-setting the timeout:
        //   windowInterval = window.setTimeout(function() {
        //       connectToVM(portalId, host, port, user, passwd, db)
        //     }
        //   , 4000);
        // ...update the chart's nextUpdateTime:
        chart.nextUpdateTime = (new Date().getTime()) + 4000;
      }
  );
}
```

---

**initial answer below**

Thanks for the detailed question! It feels you're missing something very obvious wrt questions #2/3, but it's hard to tell what specifically without seeing more of your code. Can you post a more complete, yes simple example demonstrating the problem you're trying to solve? Perhaps the function handling changing the active tab in pseudocode would help, like this:

```
function selectTab(tabID) {
  // ...activate tab #tabID in the GUI...
  if (tabID == 1) {
    // there's chart #1 on tab #1, need to stop any active timeouts and start a new one 
    connectToVM("chart #1");
  } else if (tabID == 2) {
    // no charts on tab #2.. need to stop any active timeouts
  } else if (tabID == 3) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

One thing I don't understand is whether there's always a **single** chart, that needs updating, at any point of time?

Also, do you know the concepts mentioned in [A re-introduction to JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript), specifically objects?

As for the questions:

- 1: yes, too many timeouts should be avoided (thousands a second will probably make the CPU hot and the browser sluggish), although I'd be more worried about the server, which has to handle the requests from multiple clients.
- 2/3: see above.
- 4: The [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) page lists a lot of alternatives to basic AJAX polling (server-sent events, long-polling, websockets), but I'd worry about this later.

Comment: Thanks for your response Nickolay.. And thanks for providing with the link.. I do know and implement all those concepts mentioned in the link :| Yea, also regarding reverse ajax / comet, we'll get there later as I already know what to do there :) I have posted my code and detailed comments to my situation in my original question! Thanks again. Do hope to get reply :)

Comment: Awesome :-) I like your method \m/. I will try it out and let you know if it works out :) I was on the lines of making a caching / key-value kind of thing to store variables as my timeout Id's. But I read that having a `String` as the timeout id is not good. Cool.
Just wanted to tell you that my `connectToVM` method now looks something like this : 
`function connectToVM(portalId, host, port, user, passwd, db, pollInterval, retryInterval, virtualMachineStore, portalTimeoutTitle) {`
where I am passing the `pollInterval` & `retryInterval` as well.
 Thanks once again :)

Comment: Also, please correct me if I am wrong : The `reason` I was having a recursive timeOut call to my function `connectToVM` was to avoid any unnecessary XHR queues if the connection is lost / disconnected and also, I have a else condition which when executed, makes a retry per 10000 secs or per the configured retryInterval. But if I am wrong, I better take your advise :) Thanks!

Comment: @FirstBlood: saving timeout id in an object wouldn't make it a string. Re: else condition - you can still do this in my example: just set `nextUpdateTime` to `now + 10000`. The timeout would fire regularly, but only send XHRs when needed.

Comment: Thanks! One question.. In my case, I have tabs, so say on 1st tab I have Chart#1, Chart#2. So there will be 2 timers distinct for these 2 charts.. Now I switch the tab, and I see no charts.. so now I have to stop both the timers.. Also, now say I put Chart#1 on tab2.. I would simply like to check / override the timer of Chart#1.. so that I can poll the same chart by avoiding the duplication of timeOuts.. Maybe I am asking foolish question, but I'm a little confused.. As of now, I have handled the chart[] thing, but it's not exactly an [] since it has a store inside the chart config

Comment: I think let me gather my thoughts and try out implementing.. and then I will tell you my approach towards solving the problem. But you are definitely helping me solving it :) Thanks buddy!

Comment: @FirstBlood: Note that if you're using my approach, you would never have more than one timer active. If you can get the |charts| array to list the charts you want to update after any user action, you're all set.

Comment: Hey thanks @Nickolay.. I really appreciate.. So you're saying that there will only be 1 time active `per chart` ? It looks like yes for me.. but will integrate it now.. let you know how it works out :) Thanks again!

Comment: @FirstBlood: no, I mean just one timer for all charts.

Comment: Yeah that's my problem right there.. I have to micromanage each timer per chart basis.. So what I am doing is.. I am caching the charts and checking if in a tab therez 1 chart with title.. `title1`, and in tab2 therez another chart which has same `title1`, I `call` my method only once.. So eventually the `timer` is called only once per `chart title`.. but the `id's` in this case are unique to each chart.. So that `works`.. Now to manage to `timers` is a big `headache` :( :( Thanks though!

Comment: @FirstBlood: why do you have to have a timer per chart? Why is my solution not appropriate for you?

Comment: Yea because, I have say one type of chart : which is `gauge chart`, `bar / column / trend` etc.. I categorize them by `type` so I can create the charts by type, So each `tab` can have as many unique `titled charts`.. and they can be of same `type`.. So for instance: I can have - `VM1, VM2, VM3` which are of type `Gauge`.. I restrict users who can have `same titled` chart only 1 on each tab.. So essentially, `VM1` can be on `tab1` and `tab2`

Comment: Please read the above comment too..
Now, they are on both tabs, I share the same code so that all same `titled` charts are updated. When I switch the tab & if the chart is not present I switch off the timer. So I really have to keep track of all the charts / timers so that on `tab switch` I switch those charts / timers off which are not present on that tab, so therez no polling to server.. But I have to restart the chart / timer when I go back to the same tab which had my `chart`.. It's a little complicated :| Now, I have charts[].. and I am trying to restart all charts on every tab switch!

Comment: Please do read above 2 comments :)
And on top of that..All my parameters are passed from Json.. So pollInterval / retryInterval.. etc.. So for each chart.. there is a different `polInterval` associated with it, so every chart essentially polls per configured interval.. which is even more hairy in here.. But I will figure that out.. I just want to see if I can somehow, restart all the chart updates on tab switch so that I don't get into `micro-managing` all the chart updates.. Hope that clears stuff out.. Thanks for your response.. It does help :)

Comment: Please do read above 3 comments :)
I have come to a point where I can restart all the charts on the tab.. 
`var activeInterval = null;
function restartAllChartUpdates() {
 if (activeInterval !== null) {
  window.clearInterval(activeInterval);
 } 
  activeInterval = window.setInterval(updateAllCharts, 5000);
}`
But now there'z `1 variable`.. `activeInterval` which is responsible to start the updates. For each chart, therez a new value to it. So is there a way I iterate over `activeInterval's` values.. to `stop` all the chart's updates? So I can restart all the updates on `tab switch`? Thanks!

Comment: Please read above 4 comments :P Sorry for all this..
But as an update.. I managed to restart all the charts which are in active tab.. with one global interval variable..Everything works well.. Now as I pointed out.. Could this be tweaked so that I can pass the `pollInterval` by which, each `chart` has it's own interval so that you'll eventually see many charts, updating simultaneously, but with their own `intervals`? Thanks, I think I asked too many questions in here :P Sorry about that!

Comment: @FirstBlood: sorry, apparently we can't come to an understanding :( I already commented about charts with their own intervals: "just set nextUpdateTime to now + 10000". You need someone to talk about this; prolonged discussion in SO comments doesn't work very well.

Comment: That's alright.. I figured out :-) I overrode the default implementation of `window.setTimeout()` and made a new one for my use.. and now everything just works fine.. I used your technique where I am restarting all my charts on tab switch.. possibly, the `only` way out to my problem.. :) Thanks again for your kind help.. really appreciate that.. I am marking your answer as accepted :) Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. `var x = window.setTimeout(...); window.clearTimeout(x);`
3. Store it as a data attribute on the active tab, a property on your object, or as a global variable. Many different ways. Example code would have made it easier to answer this.

---

Based on your comments:

```
var windowInterval;
function connectToVM(portal) {
    if(windowInterval)window.clearTimeout(windowInterval);
    windowInterval = window.setTimeout(function() { ... }, 4000);
}
```

Comment: I exactly have the same thing you mentioned! I am doing it. Scope of my variable is also global. But now I have to make use of the same function which has a `setTimeout` inside it.. So now, in such a case, I can't make use of the same global variable right, as I have to stop the interval of the 2nd newly added chart anytime required by passing in the variable. Also, if I do `window.clearTimeout(x)`; where x is the assigned variable, for each newly added chart, making a call to 3rd chart's `clearTimeout(x)`, stops all 3 chart's timeouts.. :(

Comment: Um, it is impossible for having one variable stop three different timeouts. When you set the global again it will override the prvious value. And shouldn't you be only making Ajax calls for the active tab since it is useless to update data the user will not see?

Comment: Yes, I am making Ajax calls only for the active tab. So as you mentioned, the global variable's value will override the previous value.. How am I supposed to keep track of who triggered the function. Since, I have to stop polling the server whenever the user switches to new tab and if that tab does not have that chart.. All my problem is to keep a track and `clearTimeout` whenever he doesn't find it in other tab. Btw, I have handled this situation for 1 chart.. since we can easily keep a track of 1 timeOut.. I have done this by simply setting a `boolean` to trigger the call!

Comment: Thanks.. But imo, won't this clear out every poll interval which was triggered earlier? Like.. if 1st chart needs polling.. I call it.. Now, I dropped in another chart which needs polling too.. So `if(windowInterval)window.clearTimeout(windowInterval);` this guy restarts the 1st and start the 2nd poll?

Comment: Yes it would clear out the previous, why would you need it to poll if you switch tabs?

Comment: Yea because a user can have same chart in some other tab, but not the same! It's a little too complicated.. I have handled every possible situation for 1 chart.. problem arises for other chart of same type which has to poll on a different IP :( Thanks for all your help btw! I am still scratching my head to get this thing out :|

Comment: So add some logic to the check. Store what is being rendered with that timeout. if it matches cancel it. Or use an object to store the intervals.

Comment: Well it's not really 1 timeout. so not 1 value set to the variable but my timeOut is more like a `setInterval` which is called recursively. So every time this function is called, there is a new value to the global variable. Like the code I have mentioned in the question.. I printed out the value of the global variable and for the polling interval. which is for every 4 secs. I get a new value of the global variable.I have already cached those charts. the problem is with triggering those events back. I understand what you said I have tried it.Could u pls elaborate on storing whats rendered mean?